# Seleccionar elementos HTML dentro de otro con jQuery

Tags: jquery

Digamos que tengo una función definida en JQuery, la escribo de forma simplificada:

```
miFunc = function(elem) {
    ...
}
```

`elem` es un elemento HTML. Podría ser un elemento pasado al realizar la llamada por algún evento de ratón. Por ejemplo, un elemento div con el atributo onmouseover, como en el siguiente código.

```
<div class"unaClase" onmouseover="miFunc(this);">
    <span class="otraClase"> ... </span>
</div>
```

Teniendo `elem`, **¿cómo podría acceder a los elementos que tengan la clase `otraClase` y estén dentro de `elem`?** Por ejemplo, para el código mostrado, seleccionar el elemento `span` para modificar su contenido.

Evidentemente busco algo dinámico y estos ejemplos son casos concretos. Los elementos podrían no ser span y podría haber varios (o incluso no haber ninguno).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si sabes que `elem` es un elemento HTML, decóralo con `$()` y filtra desde él:

```
miFunc = function(elem) {
    var otraClaseElems = $(elem).find(".otraClase");
}
```

Comment: Bastante sencillo, claro y limpio. Muchísimas gracias, soy un novato de jQuery y JavaScript en general.

Comment: qye hace .find ???

Comment: @Gamez va a buscar si existe un elemento o colección de elementos HTML bajo el parámetro de búsqueda. En el ejemplo de aquí, devolverá todos los elementos que posean la clase `otraClase` dentro de `elem`.

Comment: disculpa mi ignoracia perome explicas con ejemplos porque aun no lo tengo claro porfa

Comment: me confunde el pase de parametro por la funcion, eso me crea mas confucion

Comment: @Gamez imagina que tienes lo siguiente: `<div id="a"><div class="otraClase"/> <div class="unaClase" /> </div>` entonces puedes hacer `var divOtraClase = $("#a").find(".otraClase");`. Si tuvieras más divs o componentes html dentro del div con id "a", entonces `find` los buscará.

Comment: @Gamez El método `find` busca el/los elementos con dicho selector **dentro de los hijos** del elemento que llama a `find`. Esto es diferente a usar `$('.algo')` porque la instrucción anterior buscará **todos** los elementos con la clase `.algo` a través del documento. En cambio, con `find` **limitas una búsqueda** a los hijos de un determinado elemento.

Comment: Primero debes entender **cómo funciona** `jQuery`. jQuery no es más que un objeto gigante, por ende, puedes llamar a todos los métodos disponibles uno tras otro; esto se conoce como encademamiento de métodos o *method chaining* en Inglés. Esto: `$` **es una función** que acepta varias formas de parámetros: acepta nodos y acepta selectores (clases, ids, atributos data, etc.). Esta función te devuelve una instancia de dicha función con todos los métodos disponibles, donde cada método devuelve una referencia de sí misma. Por eso puedes hacer: `$('.algo').find('.hijo').css('height', 10).etc`.

Comment: ya entendi tu punto amigo. solo te digo que este codigo que te mostre me corre bien gracias con la ayuda de esta red y la curiosidad es sobre este punto que se encuentra dentro de .find-------     var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

           if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){

Comment: @Gamez ¿Cómo seleccionas un elemento mediante su clase? ¿Cómo escribes las clases en CSS? ¡Pues con un punto! Supongamos que `identificador` tiene almacenado el valor `cajita`, entonces `.find("."+identificador)` se traduce a `.find(".cajita")`. Solo se está **concatenando** el nombre de la clase con el punto para que se pueda seleccionar el elemento.

Comment: unnnn intereante tu explicacion, mañana le quito la comillas aver :-) y lenght que hace en este caso ?. porque se supone que ya busco el methodo find??,,, IDENTIFICADOR ALMACENA EL NUMERO DE CAJAS QUE ME LO TRAE CONWHILE DESDE LA BASE DE DATOS

Comment: La propiedad `.length` simplemente obteniene la cantidad de elementos que tienen que tiene un Array o NodeList. Como ya se dije, `find` encuentra elementos a partir de un padre y los devuelve en forma de `NodeList` que es como un array. Es por eso que con `.length` puedes saber cuántos elementos ha encontrado `.find`. Esto: `if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length)` será verdadero siempre y cuando `.length` retorne un número mayor a 0, ya que en JavaScript 0 se evalúa en `false`. Básicamente dice: "Si se han encontrado elementos, entonces...".

Comment: Si tienes más dudas mejor publícalas porque la charla se está haciendo larga y se enoja @LuiggiMendoza jeje

Comment: COMO TE CONTACTO ???

Comment: @GustavoGarcía no me enojo (:

Comment: JAJAJA ESTABAS ESCONDIDO

Comment: @Gamez mi contacto está dentro de mi perfil. De todas formas, te sugiero primero practicar un poco y si tienes dudas lanzarlas como pregunta aquí en el sitio.

Comment: SI TENGO VARIAS PERO ESTOY EN UNA QUE PUBLIQUE PERO NO ME HAN RESPONDIDOSE LLAMA ¿ COMO ELIMINAR DIV CLONADO DENTRO DE OTRO DIV ? NO SE SI LA LOGRAN PILLAR ?